# How do I filter support knowledge articles by type using REST API?

Tags: rest-api, articles, support

I can get a list of all articles types using
https://xx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles/

I want to get a list of articles of type Problem_Error__kav, How_To__kav only.

I also want to get published articles only. How do I specify these filters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[prefix]/support/knowledgeArticles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_knowledge_support_artlist.htm) endpoint supports **q** as an optional parameters which you can use for defining custom query and get desired result. If the query string is null, empty, or not given, an SOQL query runs.

```
/services/data/v43.0/support/knowledgeArticles/?q=FIND+faq*+IN+ALL+FIELDS+RETURNING+Problem_Error__kav+(Id)
```

alternative option is you can directly query your knowledge article object as shown below

```
/services/data/v43.0/query?q=select+id+from+Problem_Error__kav+where+publishstatus='Online'+and+language='en_US'
```

Comment: Thank you, Himanshu! I didn't try the first one but the second one works

Comment: Hi Himanshu, How do I filter further by DataCategoryName and DataCategoryGroupName in the query? ex: I want articles of type Problem_Error__kav and DataCategoryGroupName="Knowledge" and all the child categories of DataCategoryName="HR" Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured out. Append the following to query:
WITH DATA CATEGORY Knowledge__c BELOW HR__c