# Need to get Knowledge Record Type (How To, FAQ, etc.) using REST API?

Tags: rest-api, record-type, knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge

Here's what I did so far.
I got the access token in Postman using the Connected App. 
I then send a request to

```
/services/data/v47.0/support/knowledgeArticles
```

Here I could only find groupLabels and other things and the articleType field is returning the knowledge base such as "knowledge__kav" not the actual Articles Record Types.

[image: Knowledge Articles Record Types]

I had already gone through [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235354/how-do-i-filter-support-knowledge-articles-by-type-using-rest-api) and several other links but to no avail.

But the things mentioned in it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pull this info in the REST API with the normal `sobjects/describe` endpoint. You do need to check what your actual API name is for your Knowledge object as it may be set differently.

To do this, go to *Setup --> Object Manager*. Find *Knowledge* and see what the API name is.

[image]

Use this value in the below:

```
/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/FAQ__kav/describe
```

You should see `recordTypeInfos` returned:

[image]

An easy way to test with this and see what you get returned is to use workbench. Select *Utilities --> REST Explorer* and you can see the returned results and whether you have a valid call.

[image]

---

If you need to then query records based on the recordTypeID, you can use the query resource within the REST API. This'll work just like any other SOQL query you'd do to find record.

```
SELECT Id,KnowledgeArticleId FROM FAQ__kav WHERE RecordTypeId = 'whatever record type ID'
```

In REST API, that would be:

```
/services/data/v47.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,KnowledgeArticleId+FROM+FAQ__kav+WHERE+RecordTypeId='record type ID you want'
```

The return value from the REST API would be in the format of

```
{
  "totalSize" : 94637,
  "done" : false,
  "nextRecordsUrl" : "/services/data/v47.0/query/whateverId-2000",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "FAQ__kav",
      "url" : "/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/FAQ__kav/whateverId"
    },
    "Id" : "id of version",
    "KnowledgeArticleId" : "id of knowledgearticle"
  }, //and so on in this format
```

Comment: is there any method to get the list of article ID associated with a record type? or get the record type from an article ID?

Comment: you can execute a [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) with the REST API

Comment: I am fairly new to this, when I tried executing, I am getting an error that the field doesn't exist or something. Could you be kind enough to tell me the query or guide me as to where to get it?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but It might be better to create a new question if you have other issues outside of the initial scope of this one.